# QWidget deletion problem

Tags: c++, qt

I have a standard QWidget-derived class, but I get double frees upon widget destruction. whenever I add a QTreeView pointer as a member variable.

E.g.:

```
private:
    QTreeView *m_treeView;
```

In the class's constructor, I do a simple:

```
m_treeView = new QTreeView(this);
```

And the QWidget-derived class's destructor is the default destructor.

If I forgo using a member pointer entirely and do:

```
QTreeView *treeView = new QTreeView(this);
```

Everything is fine. Having QLabel member pointers also works fine. Why am I seeing this behavior? Whether or not the pointer is a member of the class should have no bearing on the class's destructor since the objects are being created on the heap, and classes don't delete  the objects that their member variables point to unless instructed to do so in a custom destructor.

Comment: This turned out to be a rather mundane issue. I had moved this class to a second directory, but for some reason qmake didn't mark the MainWindow class that was using the QWidget-derived class as being needed to rebuilt. 

Adding the pointer as a member variable changed the class's size, which caused memory corruption issues upon deletion. The application target still linked since I hadn't changed the ABI of the class's constructor, but the change of size of the QWidget-derived class is what caused all my issues.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your QWidget-derived object is deleted, `m_treeView` will also be deleted since you passed `this` as parent object when you constructed `m_treeView`

This happens because `new QTreeView(this)` will eventually call `QObject( QObject * parent )` and that means your member variable gets added as a child object of your QWidget-derived object.

> The destructor of a parent object destroys all child objects.

From [the Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#QObject)

**EDIT**:
Sorry, missed the

> And the QWidget-derived class's destructor is the default destructor.

part

Comment: Yeah, but that wouldn't explain the _double_ free. The non-member variable version also parented "this", so one would have expected the same behavior.

It wound up being a corruption, not a double free, though. It turned out to be a memory corruption due to a file move and qmake not detecting it. I posted more details as a comment to my original question.

Comment: @Jonathan I thought that maybe you deleted the pointer yourself, but then I reread your question and realized that you didn't